# Mule- How to remove a char from payload

Tags: mule

I have this payload in my mule project:

```
[{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"}, {"a2":"1", "b2":"2", "c2":"3"}, {"a3":"1", "b3:2", "c3:3"},]
```

my question is how to remove the `,` right before the end of the payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end is just java so you can do it like explained here:

[Remove trailing comma from comma-separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806709/remove-trailing-comma-from-comma-separated-string)

In mel it will look like

```
#[payload.replaceAll(",$", "")]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mule 4:

```
payload replace "," with ""
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.