# Python how to revove last comma from a string

Tags: python-3.x

my output from a forloop is

```
print(string)
5
66
777
```

I use the below code to have them on the same line

```
print(string, end=", ")
```

and then I get

```
5, 66, 777,
```

How do I change the code `print(string, end=", ")` so that there is no `,` at the end

I saw the below question but with that solution I get the result 2 times 1st with the `,` then without it

[Remove trailing comma from comma-separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806709/remove-trailing-comma-from-comma-separated-string)

Comment: Do you have 5, 6 and 7 in a list or something? (something like: `numbers = [5, 6, 7]`)

Comment: @JonClements that's just the name of the variable

Comment: Can you show your for loop - you most likely don't want to be printing each thing at a time and then worrying about removing extraneous things... so if we call what you're looping over `x`, then you can probably do: `print(*x, sep=', ')`... ?

Comment: @Jon Clements I have added my code above

Comment: @JonClements I am sorry about that I have edited the question does this help

Answer (score 4):

If `string` is a `str` type, use: `string[:-1]`.

If `string` is a `list` of `str`, use: `", ".join(string)`.

If `string` is a `list` of something else: `", ".join([str(x) for x in string])`

Comment: so I write `print(", ".join([str(x) for x in string]))`

Comment: Yes but also double check: Jon Clements last comment to your OP may also be relevant.

Comment: there is a small problem if I have `25, 6, 999` it gives out `2,5,6,9,9,9`

Comment: Then, you likely did not have a `list` of `str` but in fact a `str`. See the first example.

Comment: how do you mean `print(string[:-1], end=", ")` did not work

Comment: `print((string, end=", ")[:-1])` this doesn't work either