# how to find the substring in as string and also remove the ,(comma's) in it?

Tags: javascript

I have requirement where I have to remove the double quotes in a string and also remove the commas (`,`) in the string.

```
test1,JobType,JobSubType,Asset,Plant,JobTitle,Function,Enddate,,StartDate,1,CF01,TS,
NSE-GB54X-NSGC,,"Test, java. Cf01",CFGWO,CFRGNUSR09,CFJOBLEAD02,,,"Test,Cf01",01-11-2019,
31-12-2019,,,,,,,,2019,1,"3,43,434",,,,,,,,,
```

In the above string there are the following three strings where it has double quotes (`"`):

```
"Test, java. Cf01"
"Test,Cf01"
"3,43,434"
```

I want to remove the double quotes for above there and also remove the inbetween comma so that the result is like below:

```
test1,JobType,JobSubType,Asset,Plant,JobTitle,Function,Enddate,,StartDate,1,CF01,TS,
NSE-GB54X-NSGC,,Test java. Cf01,CFGWO,CFRGNUSR09,CFJOBLEAD02,,,TestCf01,01-11-2019,
31-12-2019,,,,,,,,2019,1,343434,,,,,,,,,
```

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this ?

I can replace the double quotes with empty value but how to remove the comma only for the substring which is inbetween double quotes (`"..."`) in the string.

I cannot remove the all the commas in the string because I am setting the string value to the table based on the comma separator.

Comment: Please add your expected String in post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove trailing comma from comma-separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806709/remove-trailing-comma-from-comma-separated-string)

Comment: Hi Jay, below is the expected string "test1,JobType,JobSubType,Asset,Plant,JobTitle,Function,Enddate,,StartDate,1,CF01,TS,NSE-GB54X-NSGC,,Test, java. Cf01,CFGWO,CFRGNUSR09,CFJOBLEAD02,,,Test,Cf01,01-11-2019,31-12-2019,,,,,,,,2019,1,343434,,,,,,,,,"

Comment: Hi Chandu , I dont want to remove all the comma's i just want to remove the comma which are between the double quotes in the string . for ex: "Test,Cf01"

Comment: I corrected your expected result which contradicts what you say: `"Test, java. Cf01"`
and `"Test,Cf01"` should become respectively `Test java. Cf01`
and `TestCf01`, isn't it? (so that it's coherent with `"3,43,434"` becoming `343434`)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
var str = '"Hello "my" Friend"';    
str.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
```

Comment: Hi Junge,

Thanks for the reply.
I tried your suggestion but didn't met my requirement, as its not removing the comma's in substring which is in between double quotes

for ex : var str = '"Hel,lo ",my,dear" Fri,end"'; 

and expected result is - Hello,my,dear Friend

Comment: @Anil so you warnt to remove all Commas or just some?

Comment: i want to remove the commas only for substrings which are in " ".